# How can chai show a test failure using expect?

Tags: node.js, web-services, mocha.js, chai, assert

Assertion failure in chai does not report the test as failed.

I've tried using assert instead of expect. I tried causing a test failure by missing a character in the expected value.

```
const axios = require('axios');
var assert = require('assert');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Tests', function() {
    describe('#indexOf()', function() {
        it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
            assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
        });
        it('should return 1 when index is 2', function () {
           assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(3), 2)
        });
    });

    describe('#http-get', function () {
        it('should be https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg', function () {
           axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY')
                .then(response => {
                    // assert.equal(response.data.url, 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg');
                    expect(response.data.url).to.equal('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jp');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

I expected the output to state 2 passing and 1 failing, but I see the following output where the 3rd assertion is marked as passing, but the assertion failure is printed.

```
  Tests
    #indexOf()
      ✓ should return -1 when the value is not present
      ✓ should return 1 when index is 2
    #http-get
      ✓ should be https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg


  3 passing (34ms)

{ AssertionError: expected 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg' to equal 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jp'
    at axios.get.then.response (/Users/adityai/nodejs-workspace/axios-sample/test/axios-sample-test.js:20:50)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  message: 'expected \'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg\' to equal \'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jp\'',
  showDiff: true,
  actual: 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg',
  expected: 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jp' }
```

Answer (score 4):

No matter you are using `expect` or `assert`, chai throws an error when the assertion fails. You should *NOT* handle the error because Mocha depends on the error to determine if the test case should fail.

Besides, if your test case is asynchronous, remember to return the promise or call the `done` callback when the asynchronous task finishes.

```js
describe('#http-get', function () {
  it('should be https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jpg', function () {
    return axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY')
      .then(response => {
        expect(response.data.url).to.equal('https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1905/volcano_stefnisson_960.jp')
      })
      // .catch(error => {
      //   console.log(error);
      // })
    })
})
```

Comment: Tim Wong - thank you very much. The output is now as I expected.
  2 passing (433ms)
  1 failing